# ExtJS Stacked chart labels overlapping on each other

Tags: javascript, extjs, charts, stacked-chart

[image]I have been using ExtJS Stacked charts in my app. And I am showing labels on chart. But these labels are overlapping on each other when difference between data represented by them in small. 
Check this issue [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1tii&view/editor)

Is there any way to fix this or any workaround which will show label for each layer properly without creating any confusion ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all how do you want to show it? because the interval of your ordered value axis is too high as your height of the chart is less. If you can increase the height of the stack chart panel from 400 to 800 then you can see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think you are look for this 
 [here is the fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/4fi&view/editor)
its not like yours but you can have you solution

And here is the sencha forum related to your question [sencha Forum](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?283180-Stacked-bar-chart-issue-label-overlap)

Comment: I have already gone through these links. It wont help as same issue occurs there if you reduce difference between data. 
Thanks anyway..